# Finding the cause of NaN error

Tags: c++, nan

I got stuck with a NaN error in this section of code:

```
void Robot::updatePos(int msTime){
    if(vel_left==vel_right){
        pos_x-=vel_right*msTime*0.001*sin(orientation);
        pos_y-=vel_right*msTime*0.001*cos(orientation);
    }
    else{
        int sign=1;
        if(vel_left<vel_right) sign=-1;
        float centre_x, centre_y;

        float right_rad=width/(vel_left/vel_right-1);

        centre_x=pos_x-cos(orientation)*(right_rad+width/2);
        centre_y=pos_y-sin(orientation)*(right_rad+width/2);
        cout << "centre" << centre_x << "right_rad" << right_rad << endl;
        orientation+=sign*vel_right*msTime/right_rad;


        pos_x=centre_x+cos(orientation)*(right_rad+width/2);
        pos_y=centre_y+sin(orientation)*(right_rad+width/2);
    }
    while(orientation>M_PI) orientation-=2*M_PI;
    while(orientation<-M_PI) orientation+=2*M_PI;
    cout << "pos_x: " << pos_x << " pos_y: " << pos_y <<
                " orientation: " << orientation << endl;
}
```

all the class variables are floats. Do you have any idea what might be causing this error?

EDIT: sorry, should have specified that. The function runs in a loop) I get NaN for the following variables centre_x(in the first pass through loop ok then nan), pos_x, centre_y(in the first pass through loop ok then nan), pos_y, orientation. right_rad=0. Clearly the problem is in the 'else' section.

OK, narrowed down to the line:  float right_rad=width/(vel_left/vel_right-1);
for some reason this turns out to be 0.

Problem solved. Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: sorry, should have specified that. The function runs in a loop) I get NaN for the following variables centre_x(in the first pass through loop ok then nan), pos_x, centre_y(in the first pass through loop ok then nan), pos_y, orientation. right_rad=0

Comment: When `right_rad` = 0 you divide by zero.  See my answer below.

Comment: If it is solved, please add [SOLVED] prefix to the title, and vote for some answer below, as well as selecting it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `right_rad` = 0, then you will be dividing by zero here:

```
orientation+=sign*vel_right*msTime/right_rad;
```

Other than that, I can't see any reason you'd be getting NaN.

Comment: vel_left == 0 and vel_right == 1 do not cause division by zero, because the expression is evaluated as `((vel_left/vel_right)-1)`, not `(vel_left/(vel_right-1))`. vel_left equal to vel_right (or so close that the quotient after rounding is one) causes division by zero.

Comment: Ah, I misread it.  You're right.  Fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't enough rep to just leave a comment, but what is the value of `orientation` when you enter that function? That seems to be the common factor of all the variables that are `NaN`.If you are performing `sin` or `cos` on a variable that hasn't been initialized, or is either infinity or NaN, you'll get NaN back.

Comment: orientation is initialized with value 0